# DocumentDB Emulator REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, emulation, azure-cosmosdb

I'm testing some code locally against DocumentDB emulator and REST API calls are not going through. I'm receiving the following error from Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:8081/dbs.
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

My code is in a local file and I've also created a local IIS site with the DocumentDbEmulatorCertificate. Both of these receive the same error.

Fiddler works fine though and the following request returns the list of databases:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
x-ms-date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 00:32:08 GMT
Authorization: type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dbpV9cfJJaOpXeGYwTxM8u3LtODh61EbiKw74d%2bnZCdY%3d
x-ms-version: 2016-07-11
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8081
```

The code I'm using to make the request is as follows:

```
<button onclick="db.getList()">Get DBs</button>
```

```js
var res = document.getElementById("resultText");

        var db = {
            getList: function () {

                let stamp = "Thu, 16 Feb 2017 00:32:08 GMT";
                let token =
                    "type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dbpV9cfJJaOpXeGYwTxM8u3LtODh61EbiKw74d%2bnZCdY%3d";

                res.innerText = '> New request...\r> ' + new Date() + "\r";
                request.send("GET", "https://localhost:8081/dbs", null, stamp, token, function (data) {
                    res.innerText += "> " + data + "\r";
                });
            }
        };

        var request = {
            send: function (method, url, data, stamp, token, callback) {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        callback(this.responseText);
                    } else
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 200) {
                        res.innerText += "> " + this.status + ': ' + this.responseText + "\r";
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open(method, url, true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-ms-date", stamp);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('x-ms-version', '2016-07-11');
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //xhttp.withCredentials = true;
                xhttp.onerror = function (e) {
                    res.innerText += '> There was an error!\r';
                };

                xhttp.send(data);
            },
        };

        res.innerText += '> Ready\r';
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#resultText {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>DocumentDB REST API Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Document DB</h3>
    Requests
    <p>
        <button onclick="db.getList()">Get DBs</button>
    </p>
    <div id="resultText"></div>
 </body>
```

Any idea perhaps why I'm experiencing the CORS issue? Surely with the emulator I should be able to make local calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is enforced by your browser not the local emulator. You can

- Try relaunching your browser with web security disabled. For Chrome, the required flags are `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir`. If that works, then you should...
- Navigate to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and remove `localhost` from the list of domains that require hsts

Also, download the latest version of the DocumentDB emulator.

Comment: Launched Chrome with the flags set but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Oh wait! I hadn't closed all my browser sessions. Works fine now. Thank you!